# Displaying table data column-wise in a while loop

Tags: php, css, while-loop

I'm attempting to retrieve all that data from a database, put it in a table (more than one table if necessary) and display them column-wise in lots of 4 split across multiple pages.

I would like to know how I would get the tables to display horizontally e.g.

Table Header   Table Header   Table Header
 Table Data        Table Data       Table Data
Table Data        Table Data       Table Data

Rather than:

Table Header
Table Data
Table Data

Table Header
Table Data etc.

Here is the code so far:

```
// While loop that will display the results in groups of 4
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{ $newDate = $row['datenow']->format('d/m/Y'); ?>

<table id="syncresults">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" id="dateheader"> <?php echo $newDate ?></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['nbsactive']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['nbsmanysynced']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['nbsthreedays']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this or to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wrap each table in a div and float it left? Unless I misunderstood.

Comment: Unbelievable! This solves my problem, and is incredibly simple. The problem was that I was wrapping the entire while loop in a div then floating it left, instead of putting the div inside the while loop so that it gets applied to every table. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information here to say whether or not you should be using a table because you provided non-data.

If we're writing a closet organization application, our data might come out of the database like this:

```
John | Shoes | 3
John | Pants | 10
Sally | Shoes | 12
Sally | Pants | 8
Billy | Shoes | 4
Billy | Pants | 9
Kate | Shoes | 6
Kate | Pants | 6
```

But we want to display it like this:

```
Member | Shoes | Pants
John | 3 | 10
Sally | 12 | 8
Billy | 4 | 9
Kate | 6 | 6
```

We would write our loop something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?
$last = null;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($last != $row['member']) {
        if ($last) { // $last is null on our first pass through the loop, so don't print the tr's
?>
</tr>

<tr>
<?
        }
?>
    <td><?=$row['member']?></td>
<?
        $last = $row['member'];
    }
?>
    <td><?=$row['quantity']?></td>
<?
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

The headers?  Well, typically I would recommend looping twice and resetting the pointer, but I don't see the equivalent of `mysql_data_seek` or `pg_result_seek` for the interface you're using, so I can't help you any farther than this.  Using output buffering on the first "row" of results combined with a collector variable gathering up all of the headers as an array can work without the need to reset the pointer.

If you're just wanting to spit out the results in 4 columns because you think it looks prettier and not because it expresses tabular data, using CSS columns would be the better way to go.

Comment: I have used the same code and not able to get the result as expected. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

use table inside table.

```
// php fetch data
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo'<table>
    <tr><td><table> place data here</table></td></tr>

    <tr><td><table>or here </table></td></tr>

    <tr><td><table>or here, depending on what the data is</table></td></tr>

    </table>';
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is did not have the desired effect, thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code as:

```
    <table>
    <?php
$i=0;
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    { $newDate = $row['datenow']->format('d/m/Y'); ?>

    $j=$i%3;
      ?>
      <?php
    if($j==0)
    {
      echo"<tr>";
    }
      ?>
    <td>
    <table id="syncresults">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" id="dateheader"> <?php echo $newDate ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['nbsactive']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['nbsmanysynced']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['nbsthreedays']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </td>
    <?php
    if($j==2)
    {
      echo"</tr><tr><td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    }
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I tried it and it worked for the most part, but the 4th table was still being displayed underneath the other three. I will try other stuff and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$th1="<tr>";
$td1="<tr>";
$td2="<tr>";
$td3="<tr>";

while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

    $newDate = $row['datenow']->format('d/m/Y');

    $th1.="<th scope='col' id='dateheader'>".$newDate."</th>";
    $td1.="<td>".$row['nbsactive']."</td>";
    $td2.="<td>".$row['nbsmanysynced']."</td>";
    $td3.="<td>".$row['nbsthreedays']."</td>";

}

$th1.="</tr>";
$td1.="</tr>";
$td2.="</tr>";
$td3.="</tr>";

$result="<table id='syncresults'>".$th1.$td1.$td2.$td3."</table>";
```