# How to get the same background color for the same data?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I use the CodeIgniter PHP framework.

My view code:

```
<?hp
    $nomor_III=1;

    foreach ($listPertanyaanBlokIII as $data){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$nomor_III.'</td>';                                                        
        echo '<td style="text-align:left;padding-left:5px;">'.$data['jenis_barang'].'</td>';  
        echo '<td>'.$data['id_kualitas_barang'].'</td>';
        echo '<td style="text-align:left;padding-left:5px;">'.$data['kualitas_barang'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$data['satuan'].'</td>';        
        echo '<td>'.form_input('res1_'.$data['id_kualitas_barang'].'').'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.form_input('res2_'.$data['id_kualitas_barang'].'').'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.form_input('res3_'.$data['id_kualitas_barang'].'').'</td>';
        echo '<td style="width:200px;"><textarea name="ket_'.$data['id_kualitas_barang'].'" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea></td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        $nomor_III=$nomor_III+1;
    }
?>
```

And, the view in the browser:

```
Num | Product  
----------------
1   | Plate
2   | Plate
3   | Glass
4   | Glass
```

How can I make data with the same description have the same background color? For example "Glass" becomes grey, "Plate" will be white, etc.

Comment: [off-topic] O_o "semen"? What is your native language? ;-)

Comment: "Semen White" new color by Crayola.

Comment: i'm sorry, in my country "semen" is "cement".. Sorry, i'm in hurry for my project... :(

Comment: No worries, we figured as much, I doubt anyone's taking offense.

Comment: Why do you have multiple products listed?  Is this a case of listing different quantities or sizes?  Will you always be grouping them by the product name?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the color description as a class. While I don't understand your array keys, it would look like this:

```
echo '<td class="'.$data['description'].'">'.$data['description'].'</td>';
```

The have a corresponding class for each descrption:

```
.paku {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want a zebra table, you can use CSS3:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: but what if description contains 'paku 123', 'paku 456', etc?

Comment: If that is the case some pre-processing of the color name will be required, perhaps replacing spaces with dashes and then having a CSS class of the whole name `.paku-123 { color: #000FFF; }`

Comment: thanks before,, but i want to make it like zebra table,, grey white grey white,, same colour for the same product.. And the data is dinamic.. Sorry for my poor english, i am in hurry.. thanks...

Comment: Now you want a zebra table? This is a completely different question than the one you originally asked and there are plenty of examples of how to achieve this. You can do this with CSS3. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can check sub string matches and apply background colors according to it

Comment: thanks before,, but i want to make it like zebra table,, grey white grey white,, same colour for the same product.. And the data is dinamic.. Sorry for my poor english, i am in hurry.. thanks...

Comment: okay then you can do it as i suggest by checking sub-string in your string. if exist then you can apply a specific classes alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could try restructuring your initial dataset `$listPertanyaanBlokIII`, such that it is grouped by product:

```
Array
(
[plate] => Array
    (
        [0] => plate 123
        [1] => plate 456
    )

[glass] => Array
    (
        [0] => glass 123
        [1] => glass 456
     )
)
```

Then (simplified code):

```
$css_class = 'even';
foreach($listPertanyaanBlokIII as $group => $array){
      $css_class = $css_class == 'even' ? 'odd' : 'even';
      echo $group.'<br>';
          foreach($array as $val){
          echo ' ---- '.$val.' class='.$css_class.'<br>';
          }
 }
```

Output, again this is simply to prove the concept:

```
plate
---- plate 123 class=odd
---- plate 456 class=odd
glass
---- glass 123 class=even
---- glass 456 class=even
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `tbody` element for grouping purposes.  You'll need to modify your loop in a way that would let you place all of the products of the same type in the same tbody.  Once you've done that, you can do your zebra striping on the tbody.

```
tbody:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #CCC;
}

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Plate</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Plate</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Glass</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Glass</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8xss/

I've shown how you might go about modifying the loop as an answer to another question:  [Displaying table data column-wise in a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348559/displaying-table-data-column-wise-in-a-while-loop/13349518#13349518) (though you'll need to change the inserted tags from `tr` to `tbody`)