# How to create a HTML table based on a query from oracle?

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, oracle

how can I create a table based on the following query:

Query:

```
EVENT    EVENT_TYPE  TEAM_NAME  RESULTS  PLACE
MARATHON    MENS       KENYA    1:08:43   1
MARATHON    MENS       KENYA    1:09:84   2
MARATHON    MENS       KENYA    1:07:54   3
MARATHON    WOMEN     ERITEREA  59:34     1
MARATHON    WOMEN      KENYA    1:00:44   2
MARATHON    WOMEN      KENYA    1:01:33   3
```

Table to Create:

```
        MENS

1. KENYA    1:08:43
2. KENYA    1:09:84
3. KENYA    1:07:54

       WOMENS

1. ERITEREA  59:34
2. KENYA     1:00:44
3. KENYA     1:01:33
```

The catch for me is that the query returns 6 rows. 3 `men`, and 3 `women`. I would like to use Men or Women as `TABLE HEADER`, and display results based on the `EVENT_TYPE`

Comment: This answer may be of use, though it relates to PHP:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13349518/1652962.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable with event Type

EVENT

```
WHILE(EVENT IS NOT NULL)
      IF (event == current event)
          ADD ROW TO TABLE
      ELSE
          EVENT = get CURRENT EVENT
```

...

This is in pseudo code, so you can just write it in what language you decide to use.